# Prove that these Sets Containing Infinitely Many Incompressible Strings Exist

Tags: computability, kolmogorov-complexity

We define a set $A$ to be *special* if:
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A^{\leq n}|}{n} = 0$$
I want to prove that there are special recursive sets that contain infinitely many incompressible strings.

Particularly, I have been told that if this problem is approached correctly, it is nearly trivial to solve; it can be solved particularly neatly. My question is what this approach would be --- I'm fairly certain I can just explicitly construct an example of such a set, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: We know that for all $n$ there is an incompressible string of length $n$. So we can make a suitable sequence $n_i \to \infty$ and add all strings of length $n_i$ for each $i$... But can we make the limit exist and be zero, rather than just lim inf?

Comment: @CarlMummert I have a slightly unrelated question, and you seem to be an expert on logic --- can we open a chat room for a minute?

Comment: I am about to go offline. But please feel free to send me an email, using the address in my profile, and I will do my best to respond soon.

Comment: @CarlMummert regarding your first comment: how does that construction satisfy the lim inf being $0$?

Comment: !Newb - you can add longer and longer blocks of all 0s to the characteristic function of $A$ in between blocks of all 1s. So, if you make the lengths of the blocks of 0s get longer and longer at a fast enough rate, the lim inf will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

**This argument is probably invalid.**

I'm not sure that is your nice solution, but you can do it as follows

- Let $s = |\Sigma|$ be the size of the alphabet.
- There are $s^n-1$ strings of length $<n$ and $s^n$ strings of length $n$, so for any $n$ there is at least one incompressible string.
- Let $(a_k)_{k \in N} \subset \Sigma^*$ be a sequence of these strings for any length, then $A = \{a_{k^2} \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ would be your special set.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The problem is that the set of incompressible strings is not computable, and has no infinite computable subset. So the set we make here must contain some compressible strings.

Comment: @CarlMummert Interesting...

Comment: The argument can be salvaged. Just add *all* strings of some length, then add no strings for a lot of larger lengths until the asymptotic density of the set being constructed gets low. Then add all strings of some fixed larger length, which will temporarily raise the density. Then add no more strings for a while until the density is less than half of what it was at the previous low.

Comment: @CarlMummert I think this should work as it stands. The incomputability is hidden in choosing the incompressible string, i.e. how the sequence $(a_k)_k$ is defined. Of course, your argument also works and is also simpler, as the OP asks for sets that _contain_ some strings and that's enough.

Comment: @CarlMummert : I agree with your solution. It is natural and seems to work fine.

Comment: @dtldarek: if I understand, your method aims to construct an infinite set all of whose strings are incompressible. No such set can be computable (= recursive), so it can't be a solution to the problem.

Comment: @CarlMummert You are correct. I forgot about "recursive" in the question.